# SyntaxError in Code

Tags: javascript, jscript

Here in my code I'm getting

> SyntaxError: missing : after property id  at var ShipVal  = 
>   $('#rdshiptype').val();

```
 $('.card_number').click(function () {
    $('#shippingadd').validate({
        //alert("hello");return false;
        var ShipVal  = $('#rdshiptype').val();
        if(ShipVal == '0_0' || ShipVal == '' ) {
            $.bootstrapGrowl(SHIPPING_METHOD_REQUIRED, {type: 'danger', 'delay': 3000});
            $('#rdshiptype').parent('div').addClass('has-error');
            $('#rdshiptype').focus();
            $("#BtnNext").button('reset');
            return false;
        } else {
            $('#rdshiptype').parent('div').removeClass('has-error');
        }
        $("#BtnNext").button('loading');
    });
});
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with `php`?

Comment: look at the syntax once http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the validate argument.

The argument is an object, but you did not put any key to it.

Probably you need to do something like:

```
validate({
    submitHandler: function(){
           //your codes goes here
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks. i did like this, it is not showing error now

Answer (score 1):

You are missing single quotes.

Change:

```
$.bootstrapGrowl(SHIPPING_METHOD_REQUIRED, {type: 'danger', 'delay': 3000});
```

to this:

```
$.bootstrapGrowl(SHIPPING_METHOD_REQUIRED, {'type': 'danger', 'delay': '3000'});
```

Comment: Changed like this, but still i'm getting this error

Comment: add single quote around 3000 also. Try luck

Comment: No idea how this got 2 upvotes. You can't just nest a block inside an object literal like that. This doesn't address the issue at all.